# ncurses color_content() giving me the wrong values

Tags: c, colors, ncurses

I'm using `xterm-256color`.  Here is my short program snippet:

```
  mvwprintw(stdscr,1,1,"You have %d colors",COLORS);
  mvwprintw(stdscr,2,1,"You have %d color pairs",COLOR_PAIRS);
  wprintw(stdscr,"\n\n");
  for (i=1;i<10;i++)
  {
    short r,g,b;
    short thiscolor=i+70;
    init_pair(i,thiscolor,COLOR_BLACK);
    color_content(thiscolor,&r,&g,&b);
    wattron(stdscr,COLOR_PAIR(i));
    wprintw(stdscr,"This is color %d\t%d %d %d\n",thiscolor,r,g,b);
    wattroff(stdscr,COLOR_PAIR(i));
  }
  refresh();
```

It prints out 10 various shades of green, but the output of `color_content` does not match the green colors it is printing:

```
 You have 256 colors
 You have 256 color pairs

This is color 71        1000 1000 1000
This is color 72        0 0 0
This is color 73        1000 0 0
This is color 74        0 1000 0
This is color 75        1000 1000 0
This is color 76        0 0 1000
This is color 77        1000 0 1000
This is color 78        0 1000 1000
This is color 79        1000 1000 1000
```

I would have expected to see the middle value (G) always be a fairly high number.  I would **not** have expected to see a 0.

Am I doing something wrong?  Or am I misunderstanding what `color_content` is supposed to output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ncurses has no foreknowledge of the **palette** used by a given terminal emulator.  Unless you initialized colors (`init_color`), it has only its built-in table.  There is no portable means for determining a terminal's color palette.

The section on [`start_color`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h3-color_content) in the manual says

> - If the terminal supports the **`initc`**  (initialize_color)  capability,
>            **`start_color`**  initializes  its  internal table representing the red,
>            green and blue components of the color palette.
>
>   The components depend on whether the terminal uses CGA (aka "ANSI")
>            or  HLS  (i.e.,  the  hls  (hue_lightness_saturation) capability is
>            set).  The table  is  initialized  first  for  eight  basic  colors
>            (black,  red,  green,  yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, and white), and
>            after that (if the terminal supports more than  eight  colors)  the
>            components are ***initialized to 1000***.
>
>   **`start_color`** *does not attempt to set the terminal's color palette to
>            match its built-in table.*  An application may use **`init_color`** to alter the internal table along with the terminal's color.

That "initialized to 1000" could be clearer.  The library uses the red/green/blue pattern from the 8 ANSI colors as something to repeat (using 1000 for the non-zero values) repetitively after the first 8 colors (see [source-code](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/ncurses/base/lib_color.c#L224)...).

That's the **default**, built into the library.  If you want something different, you will have to tell it what that is, using [`init_color`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h3-init_color).  The [ncurses-examples](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html) have sample palette data files which can be used by some of the programs (ncurses, picsmap, savescreen), to do just that.